# How to launch an application in Nox Player through eclipse

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, emulation

I was able to launch an application in bluestacks through eclipse. But unfortunately camera is not working. Websites suggested to use Nox Player. Is there any way to launch an application using Nox player. For Nox Player i was able to connect 127.0.0.1:62001. But after that how to launch the application through code or is there any other alternative. Is there any capabilities which we need to add? I am using eclipse Neon and i am struggling hard to find a solution. Please help

Comment: Please share you code that you have tried so far and what error you are getting?

Comment: You have to add more details if you want help